# FInding market share and year change with SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Here for database schema

[image]

The Case Problem:

1. What was the total number of purchases of dairy products for each month of 2020 (i.e., the total_sales)?
2. What was the total share of dairy products (out of all products purchased) for each month of 2020 (i.e., the market_share)?
3. For each month of 2020, what was the percentage increase or decrease in total monthly dairy purchases compared to the same month in 2019 (i.e., the year_change)?
   As a result, it interested in these three categories (which they treat as dairy): ‘whole milk’, 'yogurt' and 'domestic eggs'.

The instruction:
Order your query by month in ascending order. Both **month** and **total_sales** should be expressed as `integers`, and **market_share** and **year_change** should be percentages `rounded to two decimal` places (e.g., 27.95% becomes 27.95).

Your query will need to return a table that resembles the following, including the same column names.

[image]

Here for the code:

```
with purchases_2019 as (SELECT p1.month as month,COUNT(p1.purchase_id) as count_2
 FROM purchases_2019 as p1
 LEFT JOIN categories as cat ON p1.purchase_id=cat.purchase_id
 WHERE cat.category IN ('whole milk', 'yogurt' ,'domestic eggs')
 GROUP BY p1.month
 ORDER BY p1.month ASC),
    purchases_2020 as ( SELECT to_char(CAST(p2.fulldate AS DATE),'MM')::int as month, 
 COUNT(p2.purchaseid) as total_sales, 
 ROUND((COUNT(p2.purchaseid)*100::numeric/18277)::numeric,2) as market_share
 FROM purchases_2020 as p2
 LEFT JOIN categories as cat ON p2.purchaseid=cat.purchase_id 
 WHERE cat.category IN ('whole milk', 'yogurt' ,'domestic eggs')
 GROUP BY month
 ORDER BY month ASC)
    SELECT t2.month,t2.total_sales,t2.market_share,
    ROUND(((t2.total_sales-t1.count_2)*100::numeric/t1.count_2) ,2) as year_change
    FROM purchases_2020 as t2 
    INNER JOIN purchases_2019 as t1 ON t2.month=t1.month
```

The result is obtained:

[image]

But it's still wrong answer. I don't have any idea. Can you give me some enlightenment? Thank You

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Unfortunately @D-Shih, I can't take that data because it's authoried by the course.

Comment: Sample data is not *actual* data - make something up.

Answer (score 1):

```
with p as 
(select 
    extract(month from to_date(b.full_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD')) as "month",
    sum(case when c.category in ('whole milk', 'yogurt', 'domestic eggs') then 1 else 0 end) as "old_sales"
from purchases_2019 b left join categories c 
    on b.purchase_id = c.purchase_id
group by 1
order by 1),

temp as
(select 
    extract(month from to_date(a.fulldate,'YYYY/MM/DD')) as "month",
    sum(case when c.category in ('whole milk', 'yogurt', 'domestic eggs') then 1 else 0 end) as "total_sales",
    round(100 * sum(case when c.category in ('whole milk', 'yogurt', 'domestic eggs') then 1 else 0 end)::numeric 
          / count(a.purchaseid),2) as "market_share"
from 
    purchases_2020 a left join categories c
        on a.purchaseid = c.purchase_id 
group by 1
order by 1)

select 
    temp.month, total_sales, market_share,
    round(100 * (total_sales - old_sales)::numeric / old_sales, 2) as "year_change"    
from temp left join p on temp.month = p.month;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. This script is the answer, I never know, it should use CASE

Answer (score 0):

Why 18277?

This part:

`ROUND((COUNT(p2.purchaseid)*100::numeric/18277)::numeric,2) as market_share`

Could there be an error in the market_share calculation?

I think in this code, only 3 categories are calculated, but market share should not be all sales/3 category sales?

Just an idea.